# Нужно ли ставить запятую после вопросительного знака?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, кавычки, вопросительный-знак, курсив

Приведу пример такой (примеры я привел на будущее, чтобы знать, сейчас именно они мне не пригодятся):

1. Предложения: *Как это сделать?(,) Когда нужно прийти?* — являются вопросительными.

А если не предложения, а просто вопросы?

2. К деепричастиям задаются вопросы *как?(,) что делая*?

А кавычки?

Если с кавычками, то повторно же не обязательно их использовать?

*Предложения: «Как это сделать?(,) Когда нужно прийти?» — являются вопросительными*;

*К деепричастиям задаются вопросы «как?(,) что делая?»*

Точка же во втором примере поглощается, так?

Или кавычки должны быть использованы дважды?

*К деепричастиям задаются вопросы «как?»(,) «что делая?»*

*Предложения: «Как это сделать?»(,) «Когда нужно прийти?» — являются вопросительными*.

В любом случае суть вы уловили: если курсив, ставим ли запятую? А если кавычки общие (если общие)? А если для каждого кавычки (если так верно)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Предложения: *Как это сделать? Когда нужно прийти?* — являются вопросительными.
2. К деепричастиям задаются вопросы *как? что делая?*

> Точка же во втором примере поглощается, так?

В полиграфии точку не ставят; по суровым правилам р. яз. (которые никем, кроме школьников, не соблюдаются) повествовательное предложение обязано закрываться точкой, но курсив её отменяет.

> А кавычки?

Предложения: *«Как это сделать? Когда нужно прийти?»* — являются вопросительными.

К деепричастиям задаются вопросы *«как? что делая?»*.

Курсив не отменяет точку — между вопросом и точкой вклинилась кавычка.

> Или кавычки должны быть использованы дважды?

Запросто. Но зачем всё подряд курсивить? О_о

К деепричастиям задаются вопросы «как?», «что делая?».

Предложения: «Как это сделать?»,  «Когда нужно прийти?» — являются вопросительными.

Или:

К деепричастиям задаются вопросы *«как?»*, *«что делая?»*.

Предложения: *«Как это сделать?»*, *«Когда нужно прийти?»* — являются вопросительными.

---

Ненавижу эту точку, брр.

Comment: А почему они запятой разбеляются? В прямой речи, если в ее конце стоит многоточие, вопросительный и восклицательный знаки, точка поглощается. А здесь разве нет? Если не поглощается ни запятая, ни точка, то какому правилу это соответствует? А кавычки могут быть как общими, так и нет, верно?

Comment: Кавычки могут быть как общими, так и нет, верно. Я не поняла, какая запятая тебя смущает. Два закавыченных предложения, между ними  ставится запятая. Если без кавычек, то знак вопроса делит эти предложения.

Comment: Подумал, подумал — и принимаю.